# Implementing weighted flexible layout with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Please take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/chREp/2/) and press the only button to fill the list up. As you can see `DIV` elements inside the list are resized to fill the parent contained. This code does exactly what I want to do, but I think the way I implement this is too complex for such a seemingly simple task. Here is the code for the algorithm to assign height to inner elements:

```
fill = function() {
    //Loop through all elements once to get total weight
    var totalWeight = 0;
    var totalHeight = $("#container").height() - 15; //need a little extra empty space at the buttom
    $(".list").each(function(i) {
      totalWeight += parseInt($(this).attr('weight'));
      totalHeight -= parseInt($(this).css('margin'));
    });

    //Loop though the element a second time to set the relative height
    $(".list").each(function(i) {
       var element = $(this);
       element.css("height", (element.attr("weight") / totalWeight) * totalHeight);
    });
}
```

My question is, is the best we can do? Are there any other - hopefully faster or more elegant -- ways to achieve this functionality with reasonable cross-browser compatibility? I need to support newer Firefox, Chrome, and Safari only. I was reading about flex-box [here](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) and looking at its [promising specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), but it does not look like flex-box can do weighted flexible layout consistently across browsers. If I am wrong, please show me a simple example of how this could be achieved.

This type of weighted flexible linear layout is not uncommon, for example it is available in Android SDK as one of the layout options. What is the recommended way to resize elements to fill their parent container, relative to a weight value assigned to them? A pure CSS solution would be wonderful, if at all possible.

Comment: Flexbox is usable. You might have to write a few repetitive rules for the new and the old styles, but it works.

Comment: I couldnt find a good example of how to do this with flebox. Can you provide a flexbox solution based on my jsFiddle above?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look over it, after about 30 mins googling.  I may do a demo but don't really hav much time. 

Have you looked here

1. [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)
2. [coding.smashmag...](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/)
3. [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/)
4. [umarr](http://umaar.github.com/css-flexbox-demo/)
5. [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/)
6. [benfrain](http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-css3-flexbox-flexible-box-layout-module/)

There are some good examples on the 6th one

**edit:**
I was looking thought the firefox developer section on their website and found  
[developer.mozilla...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

I also found another example with a **download**!!
[github..](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie/)

this might give you some direction for firefox and the rest should be in the other links I have provided

Comment: +1 for putting the effort and sharing your search results. However, if you look at this example: http://dabblet.com/gist/3437894 from reference 6 you can see clearly it is not working in Firefox. I see a lot of sample code and talk about flex-box but very little cross-browser working demo of its functionalities. Hence this question.

Comment: @Aras I found an example for firefox but its more writing rather than demos